# Slick Carousel Scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, carousel, page-jump

The slick carousel slides up or down if it's not within the view-port
here's a link for it

[Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

example images:
[image]

becomes
[image]

the page just jumps up inorder to show the entire displayed div, I don't want that to happen, any solutions?
Thank You,

Comment: This doesn't happen when I try it. What browser are you using?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Google Chrome, Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the issues form of the Slick Carousel issues page:
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1662

solution:

> In slick.min.js comment this piece:
>   ,b&&a.$slideTrack.find(".slick-active").focus()

thanks to https://github.com/fglukhov